# When and how present a warning message when fields are not valid anymore?

Tags: forms, validation, warnings

I am working on a web app in which admin users can create forms, and editor users use those to create content. Admin can edit a form previously created and add warning validation based on specific content (determined by Regex).

**Warning message workflow:**

1. Admin created an "ABC" form with a "DFE" field with no warning validation method.
2. User A fills an "ABC" form (with title "ABC1").
3. Admin edit "ABC" form, assign a new warning validation to  "DFE" field.
4. User A edit the "ABC1" form.

Question: Although "ABC1" form field "DFE" was previously valid, it is now possibly not abiding by the new validation. If the field is not valid, when and how can we display the change that affects that field and its content?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the answer might be dependent on what is technically feasible or practical rather than what you think is going to suit the user best (because introducing this type of change is already not ideal for the user).

Also, I think you have to consider both scenarios regarding the validation A) a field without previous validation now being validated and B) a field with previous validation now not requiring validation.

Since this seems to be a change that can impact a number of fields, it may not be feasible or practical to provide a warning/notification each time the condition becomes true for the particular user. Instead this would be best communicated at a system level message/notification informing users the impact of this change, so that when they see the discrepancies in the validation status of the fields in the form they will be able to act on it.

Perhaps this is something you can also address at the individual input field level by adding to the label associated with the field to include the following statuses:

- mandatory (red or *)
- previously mandatory (grey or green with an appropriate symbol/icon)
- mandatory - previously not mandatory (red or *)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how your company handles old forms without validation.

If a form previously edited is valid till a new change, then provide a page notification reminding the user of this change when a user tries to edit the form. When the user starts to edit, show that the field is not validated (with the style, red border, etc.). If the user doesn't give correct data prevent the user to use [update] [save] form actions.

If a form previously edited isn't valid till a new change show form is not valid (inside form list?). When the user opens it, show a page notification reminding the user this form needs validation and wouldn't be working till field update & show the field is not validated with style (red border, etc.)